# Mac OS and Facebook Integration: Select Push notifications from Facebook

Tags: mac, macos, notifications, facebook

Is it possible to selectively turn off the notifications I receive from Facebook on Mac OS? In the system settings "Internet Accounts" I can only enable or disable the entire notification function.

Currently I am using an app for Facebook messages and I am receiving double notifications each time a message comes in.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Can you please clarify what you mean by 'selectively turn off the notifications'?  What specifically are you looking to turn off?

Comment: I am receiving various Facebook notifications through the Mac OS notification system from groups, pages I am following, etc. I am also receiving notifications about each new message I receive. I would like to turn off only this "new message" notifications, because I am using another App for Facebook messenges, which also sends its own notification and offers more interaction. Thus, I'm receiving double notifications.

Comment: Look at [this Apple page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25743?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) to see how to change your notifications.  Reply back if this resolves your problem and I can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The setting in macOS is an all or nothing.

It shows the Facebook notifications received through the API, using your settings from the website, so you may be able to change your notification preferences at:

- https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications&section=on_facebook&view